# VBA Userform After Update Text Box Order (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having a hard time getting my text box sequence to work correctly in my userform.  I have 3 text boxes and 2 botton.  So the order is textbox 1, textbox 2, textbox3, button1, and button2.

Issue I am having is that when I enter data into textbox1, the focus keeps jumping to button2 which is as the end.  I need the textbox focus in order.

```
Private Sub USERFORM_INITIALIZE()
Me.loc.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub loc_AfterUpdate()
Me.sku.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub sku_afterupdate()
Me.qty.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub qty_afterupdate()
Me.submit.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set the `TabIndex` properties?

Comment: I set the tabkeybehavior as 'false' and tabstop as 'false'.  TabIndex is set as '2'

Comment: Comintern, thank you for the insight to look at the TabIndex property. Putting everything in a sequence and using the Tabstop solved my problem!!!